# WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips, shows Tax twice on pdf invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, tax

With WooCommerce and [**WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/) plugins, I have an issue. When PDF Invoices are generated, they shows the TAX **two times**:
[image: Previous]

I need to remove this duplication to make it looks like this:

[image: After]

I Know there are a few Premium Plugins with a mass of functions but I can not buy **Premium Plugins** anymore, as invested too much in other Plugins.

So I will  need to make that little change. I can't find any solution for this.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 5):

> **@update — *Working and fully functional***

Yes, you can edit the default templates to fit your needs, without buying the premium one, but you need inside your active child theme or theme *(if it doesn't exist yet)*:

1. To create a folder named **`woocommerce`**
2. Copy folder from **`plugins` > `woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips` > `templates` > `pdf`** to this newly fresh created **`woocommerce`** folder.
3. Inside this `pdf` folder, rename `simple` subfolder with something like **`custom1`** *(or whatever you want)*.
4. Activate your **`custom1` pdf template**, going in admin backend at: 
   **`WooCommerce` > `PDF Invoices` > `Template`** *(tab)*, select **`custom1`* in  and **save**.

Now in your active theme > `woocommerce` > `pdf` > `custom1` you can customize the templates files included to feet your needs.

---

> **Get reed of the double tax display:** the problem is in the **`foreach`** loop.

**1. Retrieving the slug (key name) for VAT duplicate value:**
As you say, adding something inside this loop make it reproduce in each displayed element.
 Here we are going to display the **`key`** names or slugs just after the corresponding **`values`**:

```html
<?php foreach( $wpo_wcpdf->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <td class="no-borders"></td>
        <!-- we display the index value in here, below. -->
        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label'] . " (The key is '" . $key . "') " ;?></th> 
        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> Now if you generate the pdf invoice you will get at each line a different **`$key`** name or slug *(just after the corresponding values)*.

**2. Adding a conditional in the loop to avoid displayed repetition:**

Now that you know the **`key` name** of the duplicated element you can act on the loop with an `if()` statement inside it. You will have to replace **`'the_key_name'`** by the real **`key` name** of the duplicated item:

```html
<?php foreach( $wpo_wcpdf->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) :
    // As long as $key is NOT 'the_key_name' the item line is displayed
    if ($key != 'the_key_name'){ ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <td class="no-borders"></td>
            <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']</th> 
            <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
endforeach; ?>
```

> Now if you generate the pdf invoice, the duplicated item **has disappeared completely** from it.

Et voilà… Bon appétit :)

Comment: Thanks but that are the Steps i made before. Need the next steps. because changing the Template wont fix the Problem, when i remove or add something to that part i want to change, it will change the whole block, so when i add a char "1" to the first line, it appears to the whole block, in every of the 4 lines there will appear an "1" then. in need to switch the positions of the 4 lines but doesnt matter what i do i takes changes for all lines

Comment: Hey, @LoicTheAstec sorry to bump, but I can't make this plugin display VAT on the invoice, is that possible ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a free alternative, the plugin [WooCommerce PDF Invoices and Packing Slips](https://wordpress.org/plugins/print-invoices-packing-slip-labels-for-woocommerce/) might help. The plugin does allow you to add tax in your invoice and you can check if this helps for your specific situation.